React Native Invalid Hook Call Error with Local Component Library
I'm testing a React Native component library locally, and I'm encountering an issue with hooks. When I install the library via npm (using yarn add ), everything works as expected. However, when I install the library locally (using a path to the local directory), I get the following error:
ERROR  Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. Component Stack:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'useSyncExternalStore' of null

This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in APP_NAME(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

What I’ve noticed:

Imports work correctly: I can import and use components and static assets like strings from the library without issues.

Hooks do not work: Any hooks used in the library (like useState, useEffect, etc.) cause the error.

If I write a hook in the testing app the hook works

This issue only occurs when the library is installed locally. When I install the library via the npm artifact, everything works fine.

I've confirmed that the React versions are consistent between the app and the library.


Even with a minimalist app, I still get the exact same error:
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { FormattedText } from 'APP_COMPONENT_LIBRARY';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App(): Element {
  const [state, setState] = useState('hello');
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FormattedText>{state}</FormattedText>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


Environment:

React Native using the Hermes engine
Installed via Yarn, using workspaces

Any guidance on what could be causing this issue when using the local library would be greatly appreciated!

Ensured the React version is consistent between the library and the app.
Verified there is no duplicate React instance in the node_modules.
Checked that I'm not violating any Rules of Hooks.
Tested with a minimal app, as shown above.

